# Is QED bounded from below?

Tags: energy, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, unitarity

If we have only the photon and an electron in the Lagrangian, how do we know that it is bounded from below? I am also wondering why it is so important that a Lagrangian has to be bounded?

Comment: What do you mean by "bounded from below?" Do you mean that there are not arbitarily large-magnitude negative energy states?  Also, what has the tag "unitarity" to do with your question?

Comment: Why would you think that the Lagrangian should be bounded? In classical mechanics the Lagrangian  for a harmonic oscillator $L = (\dot x)^2/2- \Omega^2 x^2/2$ is unbounded both above and below.

Comment: Do you mean that the *Hamiltonian* is bounded below?

Comment: Yes. Actually, i wanted to confirm if the Hamiltonian is bounded from below. And what if it does NOT? this is just a bare Hamiltonian (or Lagrangian), so should we care if it is bounded from below?